# Restrict User input for PXSelector and use it only as a lookup

Tags: acumatica

I have a case in my customisation project, were I have a PXSelector that I want it to solely act as a lookup, and would not like the users to input any data via the selector and create new records.

I could not find a way to limit this from the attribute itself, therefore I tried to limit it from the events that the control fires. The idea was that in the FieldUpdating Event I would verify whether the value inserted by the user can be found in the selector's key column, if not I would revert it back to the old value. The problem was that cancelling the event had no effect on the selector and since I did not know what the previous value was, I could not revert it back manually.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use a filter. You need a PXFilter view which then could be used to display data in a grid for example.

You can search the source for "PXFilter to find good examples. One I found is `APVendorBalanceEnq` which uses `public PXFilter<APHistoryFilter> Filter`

PXFilter views are not committed to the database. Typically you would create a new DAC for the filter based on your needs but you can use existing DACs that are bound to tables without the fear of the data making it to the database. With the filter you simply use the field values rather than load records into the view.